# Javascript classList property to change header, footer and main-container?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm currently trying to develop a To Do List App. The fact is that for the challenge I can't use jQuery. I'd like the content to change (firstheader to secondheader, main-container to next-container and firstfooter to secondfooter & vice versa) when clicked on the "+" or "x" button.

```
let myFunction = function change () {if (document.body.classList.contains('next-container')) {
function classToggle() {
    document.body.classList.remove('secondheader');
    document.body.classList.remove('next-container');
    document.body.classList.remove('secondfooter');
    document.body.classList.add('firstheader');
    document.body.classList.add('main-container');
    document.body.classList.add('firstheader');
}
document.querySelector('#lez').addEventListener('click', classToggle);}}
```

**Full code:**

```js
let myFunction = function change () {
  if (document.body.classList.contains('next-container')) {
    function classToggle() {
        document.body.classList.remove('secondheader');
        document.body.classList.remove('next-container');
        document.body.classList.remove('secondfooter');
        document.body.classList.add('firstheader');
        document.body.classList.add('main-container');
        document.body.classList.add('firstheader');
    }
    document.querySelector('#lez').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
}
}
```

```css
html,body{
  display: block;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color:white;
}
li{list-style: none;}
a{text-decoration: none;}

/* Reset */
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

h1{
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.centered{
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 max-width: 360px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.main{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 60px; left: 0;
 right: 0; bottom: 50px;
  margin: auto;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 450px;
  height: 700px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
}

.main-header{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
 width: 100%; height: 60px;
 color: grey;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #8F8781;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.firstheader {
  display: none;
}

.secondheader {
  display: block;
}

.main-container {

  position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 60px; left: 0;
 right: 0; bottom: 50px;
  margin: auto;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;

}

.next-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 60px; left: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  color:grey;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: solid 1px #8F8781;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

.main-footer{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
 width: 100%; height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-top: solid 1px #8F8781;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.firstfooter {
  display: none;
  color: black;
}

.secondfooter {
  display: block;
}

.alltasks {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.alltasks:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px grey;
}

.todotasks {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.todotasks:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px grey;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.donetasks {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.donetasks:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px grey;
}

.plus {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #888888;
}

.plus:hover {
  background: #FF803A;
}

.less {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #888888;
}

.less:hover {
  background: #FF803A;
}

.list {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.delbtn {
  border:none;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.delbtn:hover {
  background: #F8342D;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px black;
}


.edtbtn {
  border:none;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.edtbtn:hover {
  background-color: #FF803A;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px black;
}

.menu-item {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}

.item-container {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.item-footer {
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px white;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.done-check {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#done {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 2px grey;
}

#todo {
  background-color:#808080;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 2px grey;
}

#gone {
  background: #D0D0D0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 2px grey;
}

#done h2 {
  text-decoration: line-through black !important;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.todo-check {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

#todo h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.gone-check {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: firebrick;
}

#gone h2 {
  text-decoration: line-through firebrick !important;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.clear {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.clear:hover {
  background-color: #F8342D;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px black;
  color: white;
}

.formz {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

input, textarea {
  margin: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.addcreate {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888;
  padding: 7px;
}

.addcreate:hover {
  background: #B2FF55;
}


.addthistask {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888;
  padding: 7px;
}

.addthistask:hover {
  background: #B2FF55;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main">
<!-- HEADER -->
        <div class="main-header">
          <div class="firstheader"><h1>MY TODOLIST <button onclick="myFunction()" class="plus" id="pluz">+</button></h1></div>
          <div class="secondheader"><h1>MY TODOLIST <button onclick="myFunction()" class="less" id="lez">x</button></h1></div>
        </div>
<!-- MAIN CONTENT-->
        <div class="main-container" id="one">
<!-- DONE TASKS -->
<ul class="list" id="done">
      <li class="list-item">
          <span class="done-check"></span>
          <header class="item-header">
              <h2>Donner à manger au chat</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="list-item">
          <span class="done-check"></span>
          <header class="item-header">
              <h2>Don de sang</h2>
      </li>
  </ul>

<!-- LIVE TASKS -->
<ul class="list" id="todo">
      <li class="list-item">
          <span class="todo-check"></span>
          <header class="item-header">
              <h2>Go to bus stop</h2>
              <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><button class="delbtn">Delete</button></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><button class="edtbtn">Edit</button></li>
              </ul>
          </header>
          <div class="item-container">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aute irure dolor in repreore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
          <footer class="item-footer">
              <h4>Starts at :</h4>
              <h4>Ends at :</h4>
          </footer
      </li>

      <li class="list-item">
          <span class="todo-check"></span>
          <header class="item-header">
              <h2>Go to BeCode</h2>
              <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><button class="delbtn">Delete</button></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><button class="edtbtn">Edit</button></li>
              </ul>
          </header>
          <div class="item-container">
              <p>item description</p>
          </div>
          <footer class="item-footer">
            <h4>Starts at :</h4>
            <h4>Ends at :</h4>

          </footer>
      </li>
  </ul>

<!-- LATE TASKS -->
<ul class="list" id="gone">
      <li class="list-item">
          <span class="gone-check"></span>
          <header class="item-header">
              <h2>Donner à manger au chat</h2>
      </li>

      <li class="list-item">
          <span class="gone-check"></span>
          <header class="item-header">
              <h2>Don de sang</h2>
      </li>
  </ul>
<!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->
        </div>

<!-- SWITCH MAIN CONTENT -->
        <div class="next-container" id="two">
        <button class="clear" >Clear</button>
            <div class="formz">
                <form action="#" method="post"></form>
                <h2>Title :</h2>
                <input type="text" name="task_title">
                <h2>Description :</h2>
                <textarea name="task_description"></textarea>
                <h2>Starts at :</h2>
                <input type="datetime-local" name="">
                <h2>Ends at :</h2>
                <input type="datetime-local" name="" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
        <div class="main-footer">
          <div class="firstfooter"> Show : <button class="alltasks">All tasks</button><button class="todotasks">Tasks to do</button><button class="donetasks">Done tasks</button></div>
          <div class="secondfooter"><button class="addcreate">Add task and create new one</button><button class="addthistask">Add task</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

I've tried to do it like that and many other ways but I can't make it and I have no errors in the console.

Comment: How many times `myFunction` get called? Is it attached to an event listener?

Comment: Yes it is in the HTML I've put an onclick="myFunction()" on the buttons

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites. Insert a code snippet (7th button on the new question toolbar) into your question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ok I'll keep that in mind ! Apologizes, I'm new. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you attach `myFunction` to an event listener. It just adds more and more `classToggle` click event listener to `#pluz`.

Comment: I don't think you can move DOM elements, but you can create, remove and append elements. Have you tried any of those methods?

Comment: @DaveCoast Of course you can move them. You just call `.appendChild()` and pass the element that needs to be moved.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Sorry kardes I'm new to JavaScript but even without an event listener it doesn't work.